# Can I use the word "dot" to denote the period at the end of a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, punctuation

Can I use the word "dot" to denote the period at the end of a sentence?

I saw someone [edited a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72700) to change *dot* to *period*, but https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dot says:

> a dot written or printed as part of an i or j, as a diacritical mark, as one of a series of marks to signify omission, or as a period

so I'm confused.

Comment: Denote in what media?  Who will be seeing it written this way?  You can call it a dot informally if everyone who reads your notes understands the meaning and does not object to it. A class of 1st graders would find it easier to understand than period.

Comment: @BruceMurray is using dot 
in that context proper English.

Comment: **To describe a period as a dot is OK**. To call a period or full stop a dot is not.

Comment: I repeat: where and in what context do you want to use 'dot'?

Comment: @BruceMurray in any English test where readers expect proper English.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt.  Then, no, you can't.  Like I said, a class of pre-school kids might find it useful but otherwise, you should use the proper terms.

Comment: @BruceMurray ok, dot taken :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use "dot" to denote the period. The name of the punctuation is "period" or "full stop".  But, the usual way of writing a period is a small dot.  The word dot describes the shape of the mark.  Some people (mostly children) use a small circle instead of a dot for the period, (and for the tittle on the i and j).

You would only use "dot" if you wanted to describe the shape of a particular written full stop.

Lambie has it correct when they say "To describe a period as a dot is OK. To call a period or full stop a dot is not."

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: (+1) The key point for me is that "dot" describes the mark in terms of its **shape** (a colon consists of _two_ dots) while "period" describes the mark in terms of its **function**. And many things are dots but not periods.

Comment: To be honest, the only reason I wrote this answer was that it gave me the excuse to use the word "tittle"....